# Count frequencies of strings (combined across multiple variables) based on a different string in another variable in R

Tags: r

I am currently working with country data within R. A simplified version of dataframe currently looks as follows:

```
# Country1       Country2      Country3 Country4
1 Canada         United States NA       NA
2 United States  Japan         Canada   NA
3 Kenya          NA            NA       NA
4 Canada         NA            NA       NA
5 NA             NA            NA       NA
...
```

As I am looking to count all country variables together, in order to count the combined frequency of  country variables across the entire dataframe, I used:

```
combinedfreq <- data.frame(table(unlist(dataset[c("Country1", "Country2", "Country3", "Country4")])))
combinedfreq = combinedfreq[order(-combinedfreq$Freq),]
combinedfreq
```

The variable combinedfreq will combine the frequencies across all 4 variables to give me a single frequency count. Country strings are mutually exclusive so that in each observation the same string cannot be repeated and is only present in 1 variable.

For the next step of my research, I want to calculate a combined frequency of these 4 variables across all observations where one of the strings matches a specific string I am searching for - for example, I am curious to find combinedfreq of observations where "Canada" is a string for either Country1, Country2, Country3, or Country4. If the string I am searching for is not present in the observation, I do not want to count the strings present in the country variables for that observation.

For example, in the above dataframe example provided, all countries but Kenya would be counted in the final frequency count because all share a row with Canada except for Kenya:

```
Var           Freq
Canada        3
United States 2
Japan         1
```

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: You may need `as.data.frame(table(na.omit(unlist(df1))))`

Comment: @akrun, if this refers to not counting the NAs, I've already solved that and to be honest that wouldn't matter a ton to my research. What I'm trying to do and what is most important to me is to be sure to not count strings in observations without the string in question. For example, if I want to count the other strings relating to "Canada" in the example in my question, I want to be sure not to count "Kenya."

Comment: One way to select only rows which include the focal country, is to use `rowSums`; e.g. select rows including Canada: `table(unlist(d[rowSums(d == "Canada", na.rm = TRUE) > 0, ]))`

Comment: @Henrik, I'm confused, are my strings Raster objects? `rowSums` seems to be for spatial data using Raster objects per R documentation. Am I missing something? Are my strings spatial data because they are countries? Do I need another package I might be missing, such as raster?

Comment: I'm using the `base` function `rowSums`. My code works on the data you provided.

Comment: Thanks, @Henrik, as far as documentation goes, I should have been looking at `colSums` for base documentation because `colSums` explains `rowSums` too and since I haven't been searching that I've been ending up in the `raster` package. I'm going to try to play with this a bit more on my end and see if I can get your results.

Comment: Well, `?rowSums` should take you to (`base`) `rowSums` documentation.

Comment: Yep, that worked. It's a little messy keeping the ID numbers as is, but it got me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse solution that flags and filters all rows with `str` and finds the frequencies with `unlist()` and `table()` (then conversion back to a data frame).

```
str <- "Canada"

read.table(text =
"Country1       Country2      Country3 Country4
1 Canada         'United States' NA       NA
2 'United States'  Japan         Canada   NA
3 Kenya          NA            NA       NA
4 Canada         NA            NA       NA
5 NA             NA            NA       NA
", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(flag = apply(., 1, function(x) str %in% x)) %>%
  filter(flag) %>%
  select(-flag) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  table() %>%
  tbl_df() %>%
  rename("var" = ".", "Freq" = "n")

# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   var            Freq
#   <chr>         <int>
# 1 Canada            3
# 2 Japan             1
# 3 United States     2
```